# How to get scrollTop from within element?

Tags: javascript

I have a div element that has some other elements such as a p tag and a menu. I want the menu to add a class to the menu when to user scrolls about 100 pixels down. So I'm trying to figure out how to get the distance that's scrolled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = document.getElementById("scrollElement");

  function myFunction() {
    alert(x.scrollTop);
  }
</script>
```

I've created a plunkr to simulate the situation. The problem is that when I scroll and I check the scrollTop value it outputs `0`.

This is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CHSVZ3UNSFYzHRMxFZrx?p=preview)

Why the downvote? This is a normal javascript question and it has an clear example of what the issue is :/

Comment: Please check out my answer, I believe it has what you're looking for :)

Comment: Yup, implementing it into my project. Then I'm going to upvote ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element.scrollTop` is essentially the distance between the DIV's top border and the DIV's top most visible line. For better understanding [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop).

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container"),
    p         = document.querySelector("p.child");
    
container.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if(container.scrollTop > 100)
    p.classList.add('red');
  else
    p.classList.remove('red');
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

h1.child {
  text-align: center;
  height: 400px;
}

p.child.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="child">HELLO!</h1>
  <p class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, took me a while to figure out why it wasn't working for me. But when you have an ng-if than the scrolling doesn't work. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

try this

// Code goes here

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
  let scrollTop=document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
     if(scrollTop>100){alert(scrollTop)}
},false);
```